# How can I solve different types of collection

Tags: java

There are a lot of questions in here.

I wrote a code this far, but hard to write in code in some methods.

1.I don't know how to do setDice(List dice) method. If I use for(JButton b:dice), then it keeps giving me compile-time error.

2.Help me to implement setWordIsCorrect(boolean isCorrect) & clearCurrentWord() methods

Make sure you cannot touch other methods and modify the method signatures.

```
package cse1030.games.boggle;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

/**
 * The view for the Boggle app. Please see the lab for a detailed description of
 * the view.
 * 
 * @author CSE1030_F13_14
 * 
 */
public class BoggleView extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    /**
     * The string representing the clear command. The view listens for its own
     * clear event.
     */
    public static final String CLEAR_COMMAND = "clear";

    /**
     * The string representing the roll command.
     */
    public static final String ROLL_COMMAND = "roll";

    /**
     * The string repesenting the submit command.
     */
    public static final String SUBMIT_COMMAND = "submit";

    /**
     * A list that contains references to the buttons representing the dice.
     */
    private List<JButton> diceButtons;

    /**
     * The text field that displays the current word.
     */
    private JTextField word;

    /**
     * The set of dice buttons that have already been used to form the current
     * word.
     */
    private Set<JButton> usedButtons;

    /**
     * The text area that displays the list of correct words.
     */
    private JTextArea correctWords;

    /**
     * The text area that displays the list of incorrect words.
     */
    private JTextArea incorrectWords;

    /**
     * Create the Boggle user interface. Please see the lab for a detailed
     * description of the user interface.
     * 
     * @param controller
     *          the controller that listens for submit and roll events
     */
    public BoggleView(BoggleController controller) {
        super("Boggle");
        this.diceButtons = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        this.usedButtons = new HashSet<JButton>();

        JPanel contentPanel = new JPanel();
        JPanel leftPanel = this.makeLeftPanel();
        JPanel rightPanel = this.makeRightPanel();
        JPanel middlePanel = this.makeMiddlePanel(controller);
        contentPanel.add(leftPanel);
        contentPanel.add(middlePanel);
        contentPanel.add(rightPanel);
        this.setContentPane(contentPanel);
        this.pack();
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    /**
     * Creates the panel that contains the buttons representing the Boggle dice.
     * 
     * @return the <code>JPanel</code> that contains the buttons representing the
     *         Boggle dice.
     * 
     */
    private JPanel makeDicePanel() {
        Font font = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 32);
        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        p.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(450, 450));
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            JButton b = new JButton("" + i);
            b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            b.setMaximumSize(b.getSize());
            b.setFont(font);
            b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            b.setActionCommand("" + i);
            b.addActionListener(this);
            p.add(b);
            this.diceButtons.add(b);
        }
        return p;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the buttons surrounding the button representing the die that was
     * last selected by the user. These are the buttons that could legally be
     * chosen next by the user when forming a word.
     * 
     * @param idx
     *          the index of the button representing the die that was last
     *          selected by the user
     * @return the buttons surrounding the last selected die
     */
    private List<JButton> findNeighbors(int idx) {
        List<JButton> neighbors = new ArrayList<JButton>();
        final int row = idx / 4;
        final int col = idx % 4;
        final int minRow = Math.max(0, row - 1);
        final int maxRow = Math.min(3, row + 1);
        final int minCol = Math.max(0, col - 1);
        final int maxCol = Math.min(3, col + 1);
        for (int i = minRow; i <= maxRow; i++) {
            for (int j = minCol; j <= maxCol; j++) {
                int n = i * 4 + j;
                if (n != idx) {
                    neighbors.add(this.diceButtons.get(n));
                }
            }
        }
        return neighbors;
    }

    /**
     * Disable all of the buttons representing the dice.
     */
    private void disableAllDiceButtons() {
        for (JButton b : this.diceButtons) {
            b.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Enable all of the buttons representing the dice.
     */
    private void enableAllDiceButtons() {
        for (JButton b : this.diceButtons) {
            b.setEnabled(true);
            b.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Responds to events from the view. This method responds to an event where
     * the action command is either <code>BoggleView.CLEAR_COMMAND</code>,
     * <code>BoggleView.ROLL_COMMAND</code>, or
     * <code>BoggleView.SUBMIT_COMMAND</code>.
     * 
     * @param event
     *          an event emitted by the view
     * 
     * @see java.awt.event.ActionListener#actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent)
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        String command = event.getActionCommand();
        if (command.equals(CLEAR_COMMAND)) {
            this.clearCurrentWord();
        } else if (command.equals(ROLL_COMMAND)) {
            this.clearCorrectWords();
            this.clearIncorrectWords();
            this.clearCurrentWord();
        } else {
            try {
                int d = Integer.parseInt(command);
                JButton b = this.diceButtons.get(d);
                b.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                this.word.setText(this.word.getText() + b.getText());
                this.usedButtons.add(b);
                this.disableAllDiceButtons();
                List<JButton> neighbors = findNeighbors(d);
                for (JButton n : neighbors) {
                    if (!this.usedButtons.contains(n)) {
                        n.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates the left-hand panel. Please see the lab for a detailed description
     * of the panel's contents.
     * 
     * @return the left-hand <code>JPanel</code> with all of its necessary
     *         components
     */
    private JPanel makeLeftPanel() {
        // create the panel
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        // set the layout for the panel to use a BoxLayout;
        // BoxLayout stacks its components vertically or horizontally
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        // create a label for the list of correct words and add it to the panel
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Correct Words");
        p.add(label);

        // create the list of correct words, remove the ability for the user to
        // edit the list, and add it to the panel
        this.correctWords = new JTextArea(30, 16);
        this.correctWords.setEditable(false);
        p.add(this.correctWords);

        return p;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the right-hand panel. Please see the lab for a detailed description
     * of the panel's contents.
     * 
     * @return the right-hand <code>JPanel</code> with all of its necessary
     *         components
     */
    private JPanel makeRightPanel() {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Incorrect Words");
        p.add(label);

        this.incorrectWords = new JTextArea(30, 16);
        this.incorrectWords.setEditable(false);
        p.add(this.incorrectWords);

        return p;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the middle panel. Please see the lab for a detailed description of
     * the panel's contents.
     * 
     * @return the middle <code>JPanel</code> with all of its necessary components
     */
    private JPanel makeMiddlePanel(BoggleController controller) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        // 1. set the layout to a BoxLayout (same as makeLeftPanel)
        p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        // 2. make the dice panel and add it to p; there is a method that makes the
        // dice panel for you!
        p.add(makeDicePanel());

        // 3. make the contorl panel and add it to p; there is a method that makes
        // the control for you!
        p.add(makeControlPanel(controller));

        return p;
    }

    /**
     * Creates the panel that contains the clear, submit, and re-roll buttons, and
     * the text field for the word.
     * 
     * @return the <code>JPanel</code> that contains the controls below the dice
     * 
     */
    private JPanel makeControlPanel(BoggleController controller) {
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        // You don't need to create a lay out. JPanel uses FlowLayout if you don't
        // specify a lay out.

        // Make the clear button
        JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");

        // Set its action command to the clear command
        clear.setActionCommand(BoggleView.CLEAR_COMMAND);

        // Add this as an action listener; see the actionPerformed method above.
        // The controller does not need to listen to this button because the model
        // is not needed to clear the current word.
        clear.addActionListener(this);

        // Add the clear button to the panel.
        p.add(clear);

        // Make a text field that can display a 16 character word
        this.word = new JTextField(16);

        // Disable editing by the user.
        this.word.setEditable(false);

        // Add the text field to the panel.
        p.add(this.word);

        // - make the submit button
        JButton submit = new JButton("Submit");

        // - set its action command
        submit.setActionCommand(BoggleView.SUBMIT_COMMAND);

        // - add the controller as an action listener
        submit.addActionListener(controller);

        // - add the submit button to the panel
        p.add(submit);

        // - make the re-roll button
        JButton roll = new JButton("Re-roll");

        // - set its action command
        roll.setActionCommand(BoggleView.ROLL_COMMAND);

        // - add the controller as an action listener
        roll.addActionListener(controller);

        // - add this as an action listener
        roll.addActionListener(this);

        // - add the re-roll button to the panel
        p.add(roll);

        return p;
    }

    /**
     * Get the current string that is in the word text field.
     * 
     * @return the current string that is in the word text field
     */
    public String getWord() {
        // change the return statement below
        return this.word.getText();
    }

    /**
     * Sets the text on the buttons representing the dice.
     * 
     * @pre. <code>dice.size() == 16</code>
     * 
     * @param dice
     *          a list of 16 Boggle dice
     */
    public void setDice(List<BoggleDie> dice) {
        **for (JButton b : dice) {
            b.setText(b.getText());
        }**
    }

    /**
     * Causes the view to update after the submitted word is evaluated for
     * correctness. If <code>isCorrect == true</code> then the current word is
     * added to the list of correct words. If <code>isCorrect == false</code> then
     * the current word is added to the list of incorrect words. In both cases,
     * the current word is cleared.
     * 
     * @param isCorrect
     *          <code>true</code> if the current word has been determined to be a
     *          legal Boggle word, <code>false</code> otherwise
     */
    public void setWordIsCorrect(boolean isCorrect) {
        if(isCorrect == true) {

        } else {

        }
    }

    /**
     * Clears the list of correct words.
     */
    private void clearCorrectWords() {
        this.correctWords.setText(null);
    }

    /**
     * Clears the list of incorrect words.
     */
    private void clearIncorrectWords() {
        this.incorrectWords.setText(null);
    }

    /**
     * Clears the current word and prepares the view to accept a new word. This
     * requires re-enabling all of the dice buttons and clearing the set
     * this.usedButtons
     */
    private void clearCurrentWord() {
        // 1. enable all of the dice buttons; there is a method that does this for
        // you
        enableAllDiceButtons();

        // 2. set the text of this.word to the empty string


        // 3. remove all of the buttons from this.usedButtons

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BoggleView v = new BoggleView(null);
        v.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I will appreciate you if you can help me how to do these methods...

Comment: You need to use `for (BoggleDie b : dice)` or `(List<JButton> dice)`

Comment: I know, but if I use for(BoggleDie b: dice), then I cannot use JButton type anymore...

Comment: Does the `BoggleDie` class contain `JButtons` that you can access? Show the `BoggleDie` class. If it doesn't why not just have a list of `JButton`s instead of `BoggleDies`s?

Comment: I will post entire code in here.

Comment: Okay. I posted entire code. You can check it out for me.

Comment: Where's BoggleDie? There is no `BoggleDie` class. Are you trying to pass `diceButtons` to the method? If you are just use `public void setDice(List<JButton> dice)`

Comment: You have to make sure you actually initialize the list and give add the 16 `JButtons` you want to the list, as seen in my answer.

Comment: Also, too much cod to go through for your other problem. Yo need to cut your code down only to relevant code to those two methods. No ne is going to go through all this code to try and figure out what you're trying to do.

Comment: So, are you talking about I have to use

List<JButton> diceButtons = new List<JButton>();?

Comment: Yes, not just that, but you have to make sure you actually add `JButton`s to the list.

Comment: Also, this line makes no sense `b.setText(b.getText());`

Comment: But as I said, the API states that correct form of this method is 

public void setDice(List<BoggleDie> dice)

We cannot manipulate that...

Comment: Also, the instruction is like this.

The fifth method you should complete is setDice. This method sets the text for each dice button. All you need to do is to transfer the current value of each die in dice to its corresponding button in this.diceButtons. The first die in dice corresponds to the first button in this.diceButtons, the second die corresponds to the second button, and so on.

Comment: You have no `BoggleDie` class, what do you want me to tell you?

Comment: If those are the instructions, then you obviously need a `BoggleDie` class. You should have a `value` field in the class, of which you can use that field to set the value for the `Jbuttons` in `diceButtons`

Comment: See my edit. I think I have the solution to original question

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `for (BoggleDie b : dice)` or `(List<JButton> dice)`. If the list contains `BoggleDie`, you must use the former.

You may want to have a list of JButtons instead

```
public void setDice(List<JButton> dice) {
    for (JButton b : dice) {
        b.setText(b.getText());
    }
}
```

You need to make sure you actually initialize the list and add `JButton`s to the list before you can do anything with it.

```
List<JButton> diceButtons = new List<JButton>();

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
    diceButton.add(new JButton("" + i + 1);
}
```

Try this for your method

```
public void setDice(){
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
        diceButtons.add(new JButton("SomeText");
    }
}
```

**Edit: with BoggleDie class**

```
public class BoggleDie{
    int value;

    public BoggleDie(int value){
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public class BoggleView ... {
    ...
    private List<BoggleDie> dice = new List<BoggleDie>();
    private List<JButton> diceButton = new ArrayList<JButton>();
    public BoggleView(){

        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++){
            dice.add(new BoggleDie(i)); // or whatever value you want for the die
        }

        setDice(dice);
    }

    public void setDice(List<BoggleDie> dice) {
        for (BoggleDie b : dice) {
            diceButtons.add(new JButton(b.value));
    }
```

}
    }

Answer (score 0):

Change the code as follows

```
public void setDice(List<JButton> dice) {
    for (JButton b : dice) {
        b.setText(b.getText());
    }
}
```